# A parameter named 'p__linq__0' already exists in the parameter collection. Parameter names must be unique in the parameter collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is a strange error I'm getting from Entity Framework: "A parameter named 'p_*linq*_0' already exists in the parameter collection. Parameter names must be unique in the parameter collection."  I am not doing any custom parameters or anything fancy, simply straight LINQ queries or stored procedure executions, nothing fancy, nothing out of the ordinary, no Entity SQL... so why would this error happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework generates queries that begin by declaring variables for each input parameter named `@p_linq_0`, `@p_linq_1`, etc. The `@` seems to be omitted sometimes, but I'm not sure what causes this. I'm guessing that Entity Framework thinks it's doing something specific to its transaction scope, but somehow its variables are staying scoped across multiple transactions.

Comment: What database are you using? e.g., SQL Server, SQL Sever Compact, SQLite, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It's thrown on SaveChanges() call on the object context, I don't even reference @p_linq_0...

Comment: I just got this follow up error: The parameterized query '(@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 d' expects the parameter '@p__linq__0', which was not supplied.  No reference to my code where this would be.  All points to inside EF.

Comment: @Brian, EF is well tested and if you think EF is wrong then you can post bug to microsoft, but in this case the problem is within your code itself and without it no one will be able to help not even MS employee.

Comment: I feel you should paste the code to get the better answer.

Comment: I've encountered the same error before, it happened when I manually changed the entity model to add an field, which was added to the database. If you try and drop the table, and then drag it back in from the server explorer, it should work. (Be sure to back up your files first)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue - I was running several queries in parallel in their own `Task.Run`s.

Each of my queries used a list of Ids that I was populating with 
`var ids = _someList.Select(x => x.Thing.Id).Distinct()`

Constructing the parameters of the multiple queries, I was doing `string.Join(",", ids)` in several of them.

The answer eventually became apparent: **deferred execution.**

Each query, at the point where it was doing `string.Join(",", ids)`, finally executed the query for the ids (at the same time) causing the duplicate parameter (p_linq_0).

Simply adding `.ToList()` to execute on that line meant the queries had a concrete list of Ids to use and weren't all trying to do it at the same time themselves.

`var ids = _someList.Select(x => x.Thing.Id).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, we can't possibly figure out what your problem is. It sounds like there are a few things that could cause this. I seem to have discovered one, though. I have a model whose primary key is an enum, so I was doing this:

```
context.Tests.Where(t => t.TypeId == TestTypeId.SingleTimeWholeClass)
```

Inexplicably, casting each side of the comparison to an int fixed my problem:

```
context.Tests.Where(t => (int)t.TypeId == (int)TestTypeId.SingleTimeWholeClass)
```

Could be totally unrelated to your problem. Posting code always helps.